# Approximating intervals and squares by increasingly dense disjoint finite sets with special properties

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics, approximation

Apologies for the length of the question.

Consider interval $I=[0,1]$. For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we can always find two finite sets $S_{1n} \subset I$ and $S_{2n} \subset I$ such that:

a) $S_{1n}\cap S_{2n} = \emptyset$

b) There is at most one point from $S_{1n} $ between any two consecutive points of  $S_{2n}$. Similarly, there is at most one point from $S_{2n} $ between any two consecutive points of  $S_{1n}$.

c) $H(S_{1n}, I) \rightarrow 0$ and $H(S_{2n}, I) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, where $H$ stands for the Hausdorff distance.

E.g., we can always choose: 
$$S_{1n}=\left\{ \frac{k}{2^n}: \, k - \text{ odd }, \; 0 \leq k \leq 2^n\right\},$$
$$S_{2n}=\left\{ \frac{k}{2^n}: \, k - \text{ even }, \; 0 \leq k \leq 2^n\right\}.$$

Here is why property b) is interesting to me. For any given $n$, it holds that from any point $a \in (0,1)$ there is always a direction (right or left) to go where the first encountered point is going to be a point from  $S_{1n} $. Similarly, there is always a direction (right or left) to go where the first encountered point is going to be a point from  $S_{2n}$.

A construction like this is not possible with three disjoint sets on $I$.

$\star$ $\star$ $\star$

However, I wonder if something analogous is possible with three sets when we consider the square $I_2=[0,1]^2$.

In a nutshell, I wonder if for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we can always find three finite lattices $S_{1n} \subset I_2$, $S_{2n} \subset I_2$ and $S_{3n} \subset I_2$  such that:

A*) Their projections $S^x_{1n}$, $S^x_{2n}$, $S^x_{3n}$ on the first coordinate are pairwise disjoint. Their projections $S^y_{1n}$, $S^y_{2n}$, $S^y_{3n}$ on the second coordinate are pairwise disjoint.

B*) With any point $b=(b_1,b_2)\in \bigcup_{j=1}^3 S_{jn}$ associate a “cross”
$$\hat{b} = (b_1\times [0,1])\cup ([0,1]\times b_2).$$
Then for any $n$ construct the net from these “crosses”: 
$$W_n= \bigcup_{b \in S_{1n}  \cup S_{2n}  \cup S_{3n}}  \hat{b} $$

Here is a description of the property analogous to b). For any given $n$ and for any $j=1,2,3$, it holds that from any point $a \in Int(I_2)$ there is 
always a direction (either horizontal or vertical – so we have four possible directions now) to go where the first encountered point on $ W_n $ is going to be from a “cross” associated with a point from $S_{jn}$.

C*) $H(S_{jn}, I_2) \rightarrow 0$as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $j=1,2,3$.

Comment: Just as a comment, why do you choose $2^n$ in your demoninator for your example? There seems to be nothing special about $2^n$ and $n$ would have sufficed. The appearance of $2^n$ distracted me from the main thrust of the argument and I got lost trying to figure out why this $2^n$ was appearing in a simple example. Maybe there is some significance, which you can explain? If not, why not go with a simpler example?

Comment: Also a visual representation of the one dimensional intervals and then the crosses would be a really nice addition to this question I think. But I realise now that I'm being an awful pedant and not really contributing anything to your question so I'll stop here!

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @Colm Bhandal. No, there is no significance to $2^n$. You are right, I could have just written an example with $n$. Any two finite grids satisfying the following condition -- "For each of the two grids, take any two consecutive points of the grid. Then there will be at most one point from the other grid between these two points."-- will work. I also agree about the visual illustration. Just was a bit short of time.

Comment: Yeah I know how it is, visuals take time. But I guess because this question has gone so long unanswered it can use all the help it can get :)

Comment: I can't help thinking there is some connection between this and the construction of some sequence of latin squares of size $n$ as $n$ tends to infintity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square